# Very easy quiz problem regarding the Archemedean property of R

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I had this problem in my quiz on Friday:

Consider the following statements:

$1$. If $x \in \mathbb{R} $, then there exists some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $x < n $.

$2.$ If $x,y \in \mathbb{R} $ with $x > 0 $, then there is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $nx > y $.

Please, carefully show that $(1) \iff (2) $.

#### What I did

Assume $(1)$ holds. Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x > 0$. Apply (1) to obtain some $n$ with $y < n$. Suppose for contradiction that there is some $m $ with $mx \leq y $. Since this holds for every $m$, it better holds for $m = n$. Hence, we have $nx \leq y < n $. This implies $nx < n $. Hence, $ x < 1 $. Can we conclude from here that we have a contradiction?

$(2) \implies (1)$ follows easily by putting $x = 1 $ in $(2)$.

I would like to hear some feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument for $(1)\implies(2)$ doesn’t work, I’m afraid. Suppose that $x=1$ and $y=2$. Then you can take $n=3$ and have $y<n$, but you can’t hope to get a contradiction by assuming that $mx\le y$ for some $m\in\Bbb N$, because in fact this is true when $m=1$. There are other problems as well.

> Suppose for contradiction that there is some $m$ with $mx\le y$. Since this holds for every $m$, ...

That doesn’t follow at all. You assumed (in order to get a contradiction) that there was at least one $m$ such that $mx\le y$; this certainly doesn’t imply that $mx\le y$ for *all* $m\in\Bbb N$.

As Jean-Pierre Merx suggests in his answer, the trick is to apply $(1)$ to $\frac{y}x$: there is an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac{y}x<n$. (We know that $\frac{y}x$ makes sense, since $x\ne 0$.) Then use the hypothesis that $x>0$ to get the desired inequality.

You are of course right about the implication $(2)\implies(1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation Professor!

Comment: @Szebo: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (1), you can find $n$ with $n> y/x$.